# Open GWT cell tree to specific node

Tags: gwt, tree, cell

I have a file browser type application consisting of a CellTree displaying the hierarchy and a browser pane showing the contents of the current node.

The application has to handle hierarchies which may be too large for the CellTree to handle effectively, so the location shown in the browser pane is not strongly coupled to the open nodes in the tree.

I wish to implement a button which will open the current browse location in the CellTree. My server side data model has parent/child references on all objects so obtaining the hierarchy is a simple matter, but I am struggling with how to apply this to the tree.

This is my current attempt, it is a method on the widget which contains my tree, and is called from the reciever. The RecordTreeLevel objects each represent a level in the tree.

```
public void navigateTo(List<RecordTreeLevelProxy> hierarchy) {
    TreeNode currentNode = tree.getRootTreeNode();

    ListIterator iter = hierarchy.listIterator(hierarchy.size());

    while (iter.hasPrevious()){
        RecordTreeLevelProxy level = (RecordTreeLevelProxy) iter.previous();
        Integer nodeIndex = locateNode(level.getUniqueRef(), currentNode);
        if (nodeIndex != null){
            currentNode = currentNode.setChildOpen(nodeIndex, true, true);
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, because the loop completes in its entirity before the children are added to any of the nodes. Therefore the first level node opens as it should, but doesn't have any children when the loop comes around the second time.

I can't help but feel that I'm missing something obvious, or doing this in the wrong way, but I can't see it. Any help much apprieciated (even if it's to say "don't be silly, you can't do it that way)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should work **if you populate the data synchronously** from your `TreeViewModel` (provided `locateNode` does what I think it does, i.e. iterate over `currentNode.getChildValue(i)` with `i` between `0` and `currentNode.getChildCount()`).

What I'm doing in a similar scenario (I'm actually doing it with a `CellBrowser`) is that I *preload the cache* (I'm caching the response for the various *branches* of the tree) using the *hierarchy* to the selected node, and then run code very similar to yours. The `TreeViewModel` runs synchronously if the value is in the cache, asynchronously otherwise (asking the server for the children of the opened node).

For example, for the following tree:

```
- A
  +- A1
     +- A1a
  +- A2
     +- A2a
     +- A2b
- B
  +- B1
  +- B2
```

If the A2a node should be pre-selected, I start by load the root branch, the `A` branch, then the `A2` branch:

```
<root> -> [ A, B ]
A      -> [ A1, A2 ]
A2     -> [ A2a, A2b ]
```

That way, I'm sure my `TreeViewModel` will run synchronously for the nodes `<root>`, `A` and `A2`.

And then only I run the `setChildOpen` code. Because the `TreeViewModel` is synchronous for these nodes, `setChildOpen` returns a non-null value.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Thomas, I think this is pretty much exactly what I need to do. How are you getting the TreeViewModel to run synchronously for cached data and async otherwise? Are you using a custom data provider?

Comment: also your assumption on the function of locateNode is correct, that's exactly what it does. I should probably have explained that in the first place.

Comment: I've got it working now, by modifying my onRangeChange method on my dataprovider to check a client side cache before going off to the server looking for data. Thanks very much once again for your clear and consise description Thomas, that really helped me.